# Unable to delete or update a row from sqlite table for android

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to delete a row from sqlite table for android. I am using following code but its giving unexpected stopping your program:

```
SQLiteDatabase db;      
db = openOrCreateDatabase("user_info.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
db.delete("checked_details", "fname = "+a, new String[]{"fname"});
```

my code for update is:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("fname", a);
values.put("checked", 0);        
db.insert("checked_details", null, values);
db.update("checked_details", values, "fname = "+a, new String[]{"fname"});
```

I do not know where I am doing mistake...Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Post......your.......LogCat.......output....... -_-'

Answer (score 0):

U have to change the code like this

```
db.delete("checked_details", "fname = ' "+a+" ' ", null);
```

Comment: @Shekhar What error?! Post your output or tell us where you are getting errors. You are making it impossible to help you.

Comment: @shekhar give your log cat results